# Tableless validation in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to validate a form, that is not bound to any real Model, so I did the following:

A model

```
class FormRequest

    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :email

    validates :email, presence: true, email: true

end
```

and a method in a controller

```
# The form is shown
def index
    @form_request = FormRequest.new
end
```

But when I load the page I get this error:

> Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator'

What did I miss?

Comment: The `email: true` is invalid

Comment: What is the proper validation for emails?

Comment: Did you have this line `config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]` in your `config/application.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `email: true` validator.

To validate an email you can use regular expression:

```
VALID_EMAIL = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL }
```

Comment: Doesn't Rails have a built in method to validate emails? I would rather not hack my own.

Comment: It doesn't and it is not hacky to use regular expression, it is wise =)

If you feel like, you can find gems that does that for you but I think it would be adding a useless complexity to your project.

Comment: No, it doesn't, trust me =) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html, in this link you'll see it is suggested to create a Validator, which uses a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for my problem with the following gem

```
gem 'email_validator'
```

It seems like (amazingly) Rails 4 does not include an email validator.